# 500 Internal Server Error at HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, httpwebrequest

I have a few web services up and running fine on my localhost. The problem is when I try requesting a response from it, the following error comes up when debugging:

```
Web Exception was unhandled by user code
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error
```

The piece of my code where it throws this error is at the HttpWebResponse header:

```
    using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = httpRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);


        using (StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream(), enc))
        {



           bl =  responseStream.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

Any tips? I'm sort of new to this...much appreciated.

Comment: Look at the log on the server... basically it's a server-side issue, not a client-side one...

Comment: Just to expand on what Jon said: go to the server you are making the request to and look at Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer.  In there look at Windows Logs -> Application.  You should see a  entry in there around the time you got the 500 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 500 error means something went wrong in the server side.

If you also wrote the web services, that's the code you have to inspect and debug.